# How does one properly use state parameters to scope variables when clicking the back button using the ui router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs

I create tabs dynamically, and each tab gets its own state with URL and with certain state parameters. The state parameter are then used to scope certain variables in the tabs. I use the ui router. All works fine i.e. the tabs and their contents are displayed properly when clicking the respective tab headers.

However, when using the browser's back (and forward) button, the variables in the tabs are not scoped anymore but when clicking again the respective headers they get scoped again properly (as expected) from their respective state parameters.

How can one scope the variables in the dynamically created tabs properly when hitting the back/forward button, that is, when going back and forth between the different tabs, how can one make sure that the variables get scoped properly from their respective state parameter.

I will be grateful for any help --- Apologies if this is trivial but I am fairly new to the game.

Here are the relevant code snippets:

**Main HTML file tabs.html**

```
   <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in times">{{item.name}}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="newTab(item)">Show More</button>
        </li>
        </ul>

        ...

        <tabset>
          <tab ng-repeat="t in tabs" select="go(t.route, t.param)" active="t.active">
            <tab-heading>
              <span>{{t.heading}}</span> 
            </tab-heading>
          </tab>
        </tabset>

        <div ng-repeat="t in tabs" ui-view="{{t.view}}"></div>
```

**Main controller**

```
.controller('TabCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', 
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {

        ...
        // two fixed initial tabs
        $scope.tabs = [
            { id: "0",
              heading: "Tab 0", 
              route: "app.tabs.tab0",
              param: {}, 
              view: "tab0", 
              active: true 
            },
            { id: "1",
              heading: "Tab 1", 
              route: "app.tabs.tab1", 
              param: {},
              view: "tab1", 
              active: false
            }
        ];

        // to set the respective tab active when hitting the back button
        $scope.go = function(route, param){
          $state.go(route, param);
        };

        $scope.active = function(route){
          return $state.is(route);
        };

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
          $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
              tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
          });



        $scope.newTab = function (item) {
          angular.forEach($scope.tabs, function(tab) {
              tab.active = false;
          });

          var id = $scope.tabs.length + 1;
          $scope.tabs.push(
              { id: id,
                heading: item.name, 
                route: "app.tabs.details",
                param: { id: id, stuff: item }, 
                view: "details", 
                active: true 
              }
          );
        }

        ...

      }]);
```

**App config**

```
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$httpProvider', 
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

          ...

          $stateProvider
          .state('app.tabs', {
                  abstract: true,
                  url:'tabs',
                  views: {
                      'content@': {
                          templateUrl:'tab.html',
                          controller: 'TabCtrl'
                      }
                  }
              })

              .state('app.tabs.tab0', {
                  url: '/tab0',
                  views: {
                      'tab0@app.tabs': {
                          templateUrl:'tab0.html',
                          controller: 'TabCtrl' // same as main controller
                      }
                  }
              })

              .state('app.tabs.tab1', {
                  url: '/tab1',
                  views: {
                      'tab1@app.tabs': {
                          templateUrl:'tab1.html',
                          controller: 'Tab1Ctrl'
                      }
                  }
              })

              .state('app.tabs.details', {
                  url: '/details/:id',
                  views: {
                      'details@app.tabs': {
                          templateUrl:'details.html',
                          controller: 'DetailsCtrl'       
                      }    
                  },
                  params: {
                      id: '',
                      stuff: ''
                  }

              });

              ...

      }]);
```

Comment: Hey Fluffy, does addin `cache: false` to your states solve your problem?

Comment: @niklas Thanks for your swift reply. Where would I add this? Apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: to your states parameters, like e.g. under `url: '/tab1'`

Comment: @niklas. Thanks but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which however looks a bit dirty so any comments as how to improve that are most welcome. The solution makes use of the session storage.

The changed HTML code is

```
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">

                <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: $state.includes(tab.route, {stuff: tab.param.stuff})}" ng-click="go(tab.route, tab.param)">
                <a>{{tab.heading}} </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
```

and the relevant changes in the controller are

```
        $scope.tabs = [
                { id: "0",
                  heading: "Tab 0", 
                  route: "app.tabs.tab0",
                  param: {stuff: ""}, 
                  view: "tab0" 
                },
                { id: "1",
                  heading: "Tab 1", 
                  route: "app.tabs.tab1", 
                  param: {stuff: ""},
                  view: "tab1"
                }
            ];

            $scope.go = function(route, param){

                $state.go(route, param);

                ...

            };

            $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {

                $scope.tabs = JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.allTabs);

                $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {

                    var withinState = $state.includes(tab.route, {stuff: tab.param.stuff});
                    var outsideState = !$state.includes('app.tab');

                    if (withinState) { 
                        $scope.go(tab.route, tab.param);
                    }
                    if (outsideState) { 
                        delete $window.sessionStorage.allTabs;
                    }

                });

            });

            $scope.newTab = function (item) {

                var id = $scope.tabs.length;

                $scope.tabs.push(
                    { id: id,
                      heading: item.name, 
                      route: "app.tabs.details",
                      parameters: { stuff: item}, 
                      view: "details" 
                    }
                );

                $window.sessionStorage.allTabs = JSON.stringify($scope.tabs);

                var route = $scope.tabs[id].route;
                var param = $scope.tabs[id].param;

                $state.go(route, param);
                $window.scrollTo(0, 0);

            }
```